R - How to print array values inside .cpp helper file
I need to find out the content of a 2D array that's inside a C++ helper file when R is run via R-Studio.  Is it possible to edit a .cpp helper file, add a write line to disk to print the contents of an array during run-time?
Don't know if R will re-compile or how R handles helper files.

There is no cpp file at runtime in c++.
